# Is Exchange faster than IMAP?

Tags: email, exchange, imap, apple-mail

I have subscribed to a new email provider that provides both "Exchange" and IMAP.

I am familiar with IMAP so I configured it on OS X Mail (*Mail.app*), but it is extremely slow, with occasional timeouts… I often open the "Activity" window to see so many requests piled up and blocked.

I am wondering wether using Exchange has any reason to be faster than IMAP?

(I am not just giving it a try because I'm afraid it could have side effects, I'd rather make a whole jump on all my devices if I'm sure I could gain from it)

Comment: Yes;  It should be faster.  What side effects could there be exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound good to know. Exchange comes with calendars and contacts and all and I'm afraid of what will happen if OS X synchronizes with it, I don't want it and don't need to since iCloud does this for me already. I will try to switch though.

Comment: Only if your using Outlook; even if it do; it's linited to outlook